# Trying to make an index which only displays the tasks created by that user using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```html
Started POST "/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-25 17:25:24 +0100
Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MnJuOlEcHfPYca7mzWk5WdEO0jVcuS+gGWiFVC++ARNmtpPTjC/9sd7AGpgV8LSybNjz1PoOIdDYddUhnOAFOw==", "task"=>{"name"=>"j", "description"=>"j"}, "commit"=>"Create Task"}
  User Load (4.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/benherring/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:22
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:22
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/tasks
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)
```

Trying to make an index which only displays the tasks created by that user using devise. looked a lot on here but cant find a solution to my issue. I've done the associations. current error is  at this line `<% @tasks.each do |task| %>`.

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column tasks.user_id does not exist

which is displaying red. do i need to change the create method? if so how? thanks

```js
<h1>TASKS</h1>
<div class="body">
  <div class="list">
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <%= link_to task.user.name ,task_path(task), class: "tasks"   %>
        |
        <%= link_to "Delete", task_path(task), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <div>
  <%= simple_form_for @task, id: "form-submit" do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :name %>
   <%= f.input :description %>
   <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-danger" ,id: "sweet-alert-demo" %>
  <% end %>

</div>
  </div>
<%#= link_to "Add Task" ,new_task_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

```html
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # @tasks = Task.all
    @task= Task.new
    @tasks = Task.where(user: current_user)

  end

  def show
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    # @task = Task.new
    # @user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    @task.save
    redirect_to tasks_path
  end

  def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    @task.update(task_params)
    redirect_to task_path
  end

   def destroy
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy
    redirect_to tasks_path
  end




    private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description)
  end

end
```

Comment: What is the error? Please update the question with it

Comment: First you need to create the relation between `tasks` and `users`. It seems from that controller code that there isn't one. When that relation is added, `create` action should have something like `current_user.tasks.save(task_params)`. This would help you tell which `user` created which `task`. then in your `index` action you should use something like `current_user.tasks` (which would have the same result as the query you built on `index` action).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column tasks.user_id does not exist

The error means that the `tasks` table doesn't have a column `user_id`.

**Solution:**

Generate a migration which will add `user_id` to `tasks`

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_tasks user_id:integer
```

And do `rake db:migrate`

> Trying to make an index which only displays the tasks created by that
>   user using devise

Now after the migration, change the `index` method of the `tasks_controller` to below

```
def index
  @task= Task.new
  @tasks = current_user.tasks #this will give the tasks of the current user
end
```

**Update:**

> (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK

You have a rollback which means that the record isn't saved. This probably due to `user_id` being nil in the `params` and the `@task.save` silently fails without raising an exception. In order to fix this, add the below

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  @task.user_id = current_user.id # add this line
  @task.save
  redirect_to tasks_path
end
```

And whitelist `:user_id` in the `task_params` method.

```
def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description, :user_id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, the error has now gone, however when i click submit task, the input disappears, but nothing is displayed on the actual index page anymore. @pavan

Comment: @b.herring Ok, update the question with the server log generated when you submit the task

Comment: apologies, im quite new to this. Nothing is showing up in the console, or is server log different?

Comment: @b.herring Yes it is different. Go to the tab where your server is running and now submit the task. Now you will see the log. Update the question with it.

Comment: @b.herring You posted the wrong log. Do you see anything like **Started POST**, if so copy and paste it in the question.

Comment: @b.herring Ok now just add `@task.user_id = current_user.id` before `@task.save` in the `create` method